# Unhandled Exception in vc++ - HRESULT failed

Tags: c++, visual-c++, hresult

I know the VC++6.0 is very old language, but i don't have a choice, i am just maintaining an existing program, and i encounter this error

```
Unhandled exception in Assess.exe (KERNELBASE.DLL): 0xE06D7363: Microsoft C++ Exception
```

And here is my code

```
 HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

// Create the interface pointer.
IModulePtr pI(__uuidof(RPTAModuleInterface)); //the error is here
```

After debugging and using `f11` the program goes to `COMIP.H` and here is the code

```
explicit _com_ptr_t(const CLSID& clsid, IUnknown* pOuter = NULL, DWORD dwClsContext = CLSCTX_ALL) throw(_com_error)
    : m_pInterface(NULL)
{
    HRESULT hr = CreateInstance(clsid, pOuter, dwClsContext); 
    //the program goes to CreateInstance Method

    if (FAILED(hr) && (hr != E_NOINTERFACE)) {
        _com_issue_error(hr); 
        //the program goes here and show the error msg
    }
}
```

And Here is the `CreateInstance`

```
HRESULT CreateInstance(const CLSID& rclsid, IUnknown* pOuter = NULL, DWORD dwClsContext = CLSCTX_ALL) throw()
{
    HRESULT hr;

    _Release();

    if (dwClsContext & (CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER)) {
        IUnknown* pIUnknown;

        hr = CoCreateInstance(rclsid, pOuter, dwClsContext, __uuidof(IUnknown), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pIUnknown));

        if (FAILED(hr)) { 
           // the program goes here and return the hr
            return hr;
        }

        hr = OleRun(pIUnknown);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            hr = pIUnknown->QueryInterface(GetIID(), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_pInterface));
        }

        pIUnknown->Release();
    }
    else {
        hr = CoCreateInstance(rclsid, pOuter, dwClsContext, GetIID(), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_pInterface));
    }

    return hr;
}
```

I don't know what's the error here, this is header file and i think there's no error here. Any Idea how to fix this thing?

**Updated**

in my `RPTAInterface.tlh` i saw the declaration of `RPTAModuleInterface`

```
struct /* coclass */ RPTAModuleInterface;

struct __declspec(uuid("d6134a6a-a08e-36ab-a4c0-c03c35aad201"))
RPTAModuleInterface;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_com_issue_error()` throws a `_com_error` exception that you are not catching.  You need to wrap your code in a `try/catch`, eg:

```
try
{
    IModulePtr pI(__uuidof(RPTAModuleInterface));
    // ... 
}
catch(const _com_error& e)
{
    // e.Error() will return the HRESULT value
    // ...
}
```

Clearly `CoCreateInstance()` is failing.  There is likely no library installed on the machine that registers the CoClass for `RPTAModuleInterface`, so it cannot be created.  But you will have to look at the actual `HRESULT` to be sure why `CoCreateInstance()` is failing.

Comment: The error says `0x0022a360 Class not registered` How can i fix it? Help me pls

Comment: You have to make sure the EXE/DLL that implements the class you are trying to access is actually installed and registered with the OS.  Assuming it is, I have a feeling that `RPTAModuleInterface` is probably the wrong value to use. Its looks like it might be an interface identifier rather than a class identifier. `CoCreateInstance()` is expecting a class identifier, not an interface identifier. You do understand the difference between them, right? Where did you get the idea to use `__uuidof(RPTAModuleInterface)` to begin with?

Comment: that's not my code, they just saw error on application and the error comes from that code, and i really don't understands what's the meaning of that.. by the way the `RPTAModuleInterface` declared as `struct /* coclass */ RPTAModuleInterface;`

Comment: If `RPTAModuleInterface` is the correct CoClass, then the EXE/DLL that implements the CoClass is not registered with the OS.  You are going to have to hunt down which application that belongs to and make sure it is installed correctly, we can't do that for you here. And BTW, `0x0022a360` is not a failure `HRESULT` value, are you sure that is the actual `HRESULT` that `CoCreateInstance()` is returning? The `"Class not registered"` error message is normally associated with `HRESULT` value `0x80040154` instead.

Comment: i just add quick watch and put e.ErrorMessage(); and the value is `0x0022a360 Class not registered`

Comment: i try to search .dll files in the folder of my application and saw RPTAInterface.dll and i tried to register it using regsvr32 but it didn't work, and then i saw that RPTAInterface.dll.config is the complete name of this app, how can i register the .dll.config file?

Comment: A .config file is a strong hint that this server was implemented in .NET.  Which are registered a different way, regsvr32 cannot work.  You could try Regasm.exe but it is rather important to get support from the software owner so you know how to do this properly.

Comment: regasm.exe is part of the .NET framework, which is a Windows system component that you can [download from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/net/downloads) if you don't already have it (you likely already do).

Comment: i found it, what file should i register? .tlb?